# OpenGL Resize Window -> objects are “moved / translated”

Tags: opengl

When the resize event of the window is called, the objects are moved out of the viewport / screen.

The link below is a video to show what happening is:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1dBnOqBDUBNCQrwr7ChFlpS8vbBQ6wfKh/view?usp=sharing

**I just found out that it just happens whin using QT Windowing. It did not happend with GLFW...**  wooow

I use the following code:

```
void Renderer::resize(int width, int height) {
    RendererSettings* settings = RendererSettings::getInstance();

    settings->setSize(width, height);

    glViewport(0, 0, width, height);    

    if (camera != nullptr) 
    {
        float aspectRatio = float(width) / float(height);
        camera->updateProjectionPerspectiveAspect(aspectRatio);
    }
}
```

I do not change the camera anymore.

The `updateProjectionPerspectiveAspect` is the same of `glFrustum(FoV, aspect, near, far)`. but the data others parameters are kept the same.

```
void Camera::setProjectionPerspective(float fieldOfView, float aspectRatio, float near, float far) {
this->fieldOfView = fieldOfView;
this->aspectRatio = aspectRatio;
this->nearFrustum = near;
this->farFrustum = far;

float xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax;       // Dimensions of near clipping plane
float xFmin, xFmax, yFmin, yFmax;   // Dimensions of far  clipping plane

// Do the Math for the near clipping plane
ymax = near * tanf(float(fieldOfView * PI_DIV_360));
ymin = -ymax;
xmin = ymin * aspectRatio;
xmax = -xmin;

// Construct the projection matrix
projectionMatrix = Mat4f::identity();
projectionMatrix[0] = (2.0f * near) / (xmax - xmin);
projectionMatrix[5] = (2.0f * near) / (ymax - ymin);
projectionMatrix[8] = (xmax + xmin) / (xmax - xmin);
projectionMatrix[9] = (ymax + ymin) / (ymax - ymin);
projectionMatrix[10] = -((far + near) / (far - near));
projectionMatrix[11] = -1.0f;
projectionMatrix[14] = -((2.0f * far * near) / (far - near));
projectionMatrix[15] = 0.0f;   }
```

- Camera parameter is not null and this event "resize" is called some times during the resizing. The parameters width and height are corrects.

Comment: Hello , what you are using is not normal OpenGL you have some kind of extra API covering it. Please specify your tools or if you don't know show us your includes

Comment: Hi, did you log the `width` and `height` values? Are they correct? Furthermore is `camera` `null` or does the `if`branch get executed?

Comment: @tomerzeitune The updateProjectionPerspectiveAspect is the same of glFrustum. In OpenGL ES, it is not used, so the code above is OpenGL.

Comment: @bitflip-at the parameters are right and the camera is not null. I update the projection matrix camera only.

Comment: @Bruno so is this openGL ES ? I don't understand whats this camera class.

Comment: Could you show the code for `updateProjectionPerspectiveAspect(aspectRatio);` I think the error must be made there.

Comment: @tomerzeitune the folliwing code is to be worked in Opengl or opengl ES. Due to this fact, I do not use some specific opengl functions (fixed pipeline) such as glFrustum, glMatrix ...

Comment: @bitflip-at   I edited the question and added the code that is called by updateProjectionPerspectiveAspect.

Comment: do you have any specific reason to not use glm library (which compiles everywhere) to use directly `glm::perspective(for, ratiom, near, far)` to compute the matrix?

Comment: @Jack  I use my own library because: Made with high legibility - clean code;
    Refactor friendly - covered by unit tests;
    Built with Microsoft Studio or VSCode or whatver tools with CMake support;
    Take advantage with C++11 features;

Comment: glm already has C++11 advantage, has clean code, has unit tests and more importantly it already works. I don't see the point in reinventing the wheel if you don't have a precise purpose.

Comment: @Bruno where do you compute the Model View Projectin Matrix you send to the shader ? You sure your project matrix makes it to there ?

Comment: @tomerzeitune I have been using this code for about 6 months (including shader), but I going to check out if it is really corret when resizing.

Comment: @Bruno yeah im just thinking maybe the MVP matrix is constructed on startup and not every frame

Comment: @tomerzeitune Yes, you are right. Yesterday I moved the code to reconstruct this matrix only on init and resize methods. After that, the matrix is stored (memory) and used to draw every frame. Do you see any problem ?

Comment: @Bruno yes I think this is a big problem since you want to change the view matrix and the model matrix pretty much every frame and even multiple times etch frame. Let's say you render a few moving objects  on the screen and your camera moves. You must recreate the MVP matrix pretty much every draw call for dynamic scenes since your Model and View matrices can change. But make sure you multiply the coords with the MVP on the shader for speed.

Comment: @tomerzeitune the MVP matrix is created each frame. ProjectionMatrix (created on init and resize) * viewMatrix (created on Init) * modelMatrix (created on init and used to translate... rotate... etc)

Comment: @Bruno The code for calculation the projection matrix is correct. If your do, what you told us in your last comment: *"ProjectionMatrix (created on init and resize)"*, then everything should work. This means, the issue has to be somewhere at the way from `Renderer::resize` to the use of `projectionMatrix` .

Comment: @Rabbid76 the video below explain better: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1dBnOqBDUBNCQrwr7ChFlpS8vbBQ6wfKh/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Hey Bruno did you solve your Problem? If not  i guess i/we need to look at the code because the error most likely is somewhere else.Could you share it on github/ google drive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was on QT Windowing. It was solved using the following code to resize:

```
void QtOpenGLRenderer::resizeEvent(QResizeEvent* event) {
QSize size = event->size();

if (event->oldSize().isEmpty()) 
{
    initialScreenSize = size;
    return;
}

size = parentWidget->size();

float deltaX = size.width() - initialScreenSize.width();
float deltaY = size.height() - initialScreenSize.height();

renderer->resize(size.width() - deltaX, size.height() - deltaY); }
```

Answer (score 1):

I think your projection Matrix is wrong, mainly because you don't use the variable `aspectRatio` at all, but the way you do it it looks correct..? (So it's just me guessing :P)

Here is how i did my projection Matrix in C using an aspect ratio argument, maybe this helps

```
mat4 set_perspective_matrix(GLfloat fov, GLfloat aspect, GLfloat nearPlane, GLfloat farPlane)
{

    mat4  p;

    GLfloat f = 1.0/ tan(fov * 3.1415926/360.0);
    GLfloat c1 = -(farPlane + nearPlane) / (farPlane - nearPlane);
    GLfloat c2 = -(2.0 * farPlane * nearPlane) / (farPlane - nearPlane);

    p._[0] = f/aspect;
    p._[1] = 0.0;
    p._[2] = 0.0;
    p._[3] = 0.0;

    p._[4] = 0.0;
    p._[5] = f;
    p._[6] = 0.0;
    p._[7] = 0.0;

    p._[8]  = 0.0;
    p._[9]  = 0.0;
    p._[10] = c1;
    p._[11] = c2;

    p._[12] = 0.0;
    p._[13] = 0.0;
    p._[14] =-1.0;
    p._[15] = 0.0; 

    return p;
}
```

Here is a good article describing the setup of a projection matrix: [The Perspective Matrix](https://www.scratchapixel.com/lessons/3d-basic-rendering/perspective-and-orthographic-projection-matrix/opengl-perspective-projection-matrix)

Comment: He does use the aspect ratio for the projection matrix

Comment: Oh i see. (I'm lost without code coloring) Well maybe this still helps

Comment: @bitflip-at   I did some jobs with this perspective Matrix, such as BSP Tree 3D, but I think I never resized the resized. I will try out your suggestion this night. You are may right.

Comment: @bitflip-at For the use with OpenGL this projection matrix would have to be transposed.

Comment: @bitflip-at unfortunately I tried out the code and the same thing has happend. When I resize the objects are translated to the right border of the window. but thank you a lot for your tips.

Comment: @bitflip-at I recorded a video to explain better.  https://drive.google.com/file/d/1dBnOqBDUBNCQrwr7ChFlpS8vbBQ6wfKh/view?usp=sharing